# UWP app WebView.NavigateToString() Iframe Javascript Access Denied

Tags: javascript, iframe, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to get a UWP (Windows 10) app with a WebView to work with the IFrame / JS implementation of YouTube.

An example of HTML which I am trying to get to display can be found at this link :
https://gist.github.com/Sonictrio/3066a56a36dbabd754adfd887470b184

It's straight forward IFrame / JS implementation which allows the video player communicate with the page and change the boarder colour depending on the players state.

This works if the WebView component loads the HTML as `Source="ms-appx-web://.....html`  or in C# as `webView1.Navigate("ms-appx-web:///.....html");`  but **not** if provided by `NavigateToString()`

A lot of work goes on to construct the html template so we need to build the content and use `NavigateToString(String)`.

Using `NavigateToString()` throws are Access errors thrown by the javascript which prevent the interaction desired. (image below)

Is there any way I can get this to work with `NavigateToString()`?

[image: Error - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied]

Comment: How you get the `String` used in `NavigateToString` method? I've tested with you HTML string and it works well in my side.

Comment: hey @JayZuo-MSFT Thanks for your response. Do you see the changing border colour?


The string is just loaded from file in the example. In the live app it loads a number of templates and merges them depending on the content that needs to be displayed.

Comment: No, the border color didn't change. I tested your html with Edge and it also didn't change. I'm not familiar with YouTube IFrame API, not sure why it won't work here. ):

Comment: Thanks @JayZuo-MSFT. I'm guessing that the webview is like an iframe and without a source or host domain it then has security issues that you'd experience with an iframe without a src supplied. :-/
Opening the html file locally `(file:///....)` in Edge shows the same behavior, where as it hosted online `(http://...)` works fine.